# What are the Klingon Vessels in the Battle of the Binary Stars?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In the Star Trek Discover [S1:E2](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_at_the_Binary_Stars_(episode)) episode *Battle of the Binary Stars*, we see a number Klingon Vessels. These are referred to as Klingon D7s.

In discovery, they look like this:
[image]

My understanding was that the Klingon D7 looked like this:
[image]

My question is: **What are the Klingon Vessels in the Battle of the Binary Stars?**

Comment: Where are they reffered to as D7?  (btw don't forget they visually redesigned QUITE a lot.....see for example the klingon brid of prey). Furthermore they changed also a few tidbits of the lore.......like the klingons having a cloaking device (in tos they just gained it through a deal with the romulans in one episode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough they're actually [referred to](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-trek-discovery-2017&episode=s01e02) as 'Klingon Vessels' throughout this episode.